Is it grammatically correct to write: "It needs not to be known"? For an academic writing, is it correct to say: "she thought there will be".?
Is it grammatically correct to write "she thought there will be no one by her side at her lowest"?
Or it should be "she thinks there will be no by her side at her lowest

There are several questions here, and those in the title are different from that in the body text.

Ok, this is editing which we don't do here. But since you are new, I will give you a hand:  You have to decide whether you want to use past or present tense: I thought he was late. versus I think he is late.

If you were to choose past-tense thought  then the decision is between direct and indirect "speech".  (Thoughts spoken to oneself qualify as speech when presented in a narrative. ) She thought there would be no one by her side.    She thought "There will be no one by my side".
